# IKvm and wcf serialization error

Tags: c#, .net, ikvm

I have java object that can access by using `ikvm` in `.net.object` is successfully fill and manipulate in `WCF layer`. But after retrieve object from WCF to Client, client side error populate.

```
"An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/wcf/Service1/. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details".
```

I am using `wsHttpbinding`. Please help to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Error occurs by indication of missing [DataMember],][DataContract] attributes which need to communicate with wcf client.

It is impossible to use ikvm object in .net with WCF. you can fill it, but can not send it to the client. Because ikvm object does not have the [datacontract],[Datamember] attributes. So my opinion is do  not use ikvm if you use .net WCF...